# Prevent control-D to be echoed in terminal

Tags: c, readline, eof

When I use readline function and type control-D to tell my program it reached EOF, `^D` is echoed in the terminal.

I would like to remove it or to replace it by another message.

I tried `stty -echoctl` command but it doesn't work.

I'm using ZSH with Oh My Zsh and iTerm2.

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<string.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<unistd.h>
# include<sys/types.h>
# include<sys/wait.h>
# include<readline/readline.h>
# include<readline/history.h>

int input(void)
{
    char    *buf;
 
    buf = readline("Please write the argument:\n");
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Quitting the program\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if(!input())
            continue;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I don't know what I can try now, I checked lots of Stack Overflow threads and didn't find anything.

Comment: OT: `# include<stdio.h>`: this is odd. Usually C programmers write `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Using Arch Linux, bash and xfce4-terminal, running plain `cat`, I'm not seeing ^D in the terminal. Not in zsh either. It might depend on the terminal.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the header from a thread, that's why @Jabberwocky

Comment: Yes I noticed it @Thomas, however I really need it to work as expected for ZSH too

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. What is it that you want to achieve with that?

Comment: I think I'm asking to good question: I want to prevent `^D`to be echoed in the terminal when my program reaches EOF

Answer (score 1):

Although it looks like you are using the readline library, you're actually using a compatibility layer built on top of the [BSD libedit library](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libedit/?sortby=date#dirlist), which is what is provided by default by Mac OS. So you can expect some things to work a bit differently.

Unfortunately, libedit is not well-documented. It appears to be possible to modify the binding of the Ctrl-D key by creating a file name `.editrc` in your home directory, and inserting the line:

```
bind ^D ed-end-of-file
```

That will apply the change to all applications which use the `libedit` library, which may be a bit drastic. To make it apply only to your program, you can insert the line:

```
    rl_readline_name = "progname";
```

at the beginning of your program, before the first time you call `readline`. Change `progname` to whatever you want to use as a tag for your program. Then you can change the `editrc` command to the following (using the same tag for `progname`):

```
progname:bind ^D ed-end-of-file
```

At least, that worked on an Ubuntu system.

Another option would be to just install GNU readline on your Mac. According to the [GNU readline home page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Distributions):

> MacOS X users may obtain MacOS X packages for readline-8.0 from [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/readline/summary), readline-7.0 from [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/readline7), or readline-8.0 from [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula/readline.rb).

Then you'll have to make sure you build your program with GNU readline instead of the libedit shim.

Doing that will make also make the prompt work the way it reads (i.e., the prompt includes a newline). I don't know if that's what you want, though.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is basically to have a function that reads AND manually print every character so that you can intercept characters that shouldn't be printed. Here is an idea to get started:

```
int ch;
char buf[SIZE] = {0};
char *p = buf;

while(1) {
    ch = getchar();
    if(ch == EOF) { 
        p[1] = 0;
        break;
    }
    putchar(ch);
    *p++ = ch;
}
```

You would probably like to treat backspace `'\b'` in a special way. Like decrementing `p`, but watch out for going out of bounds.